# How do you concatenate several arrays into one?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, reduce

```
const sumAll = function (min, max) {
  const allSums = [];
  const initialValue = 0;

  for (let i = min; i <= max; i++) {
    allSums.push([i]);
  }
  console.log(allSums); // 

  let sumTotal = allSums.reduce(function (acc, curr) {
    acc += curr;
    return acc;
  }, initialValue);

  console.log(sumTotal);
};
```

sumAll(1, 4) returns 01234 instead of 10.

I can see that allSums is 4 arrays inside of an array. How would I go about concatenating them? Thank you for the help!

Comment: Why are you pushing in an array? You are making `[[1],[2],[3],[4]]` and you loop over and are adding `0 +[1]`. It is unclear why you need to make the array at all. Just causing an extra loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to create an array at all, you can `Array#push` the value directly. That's the goal, right? So,

```
allSums.push([i]); //or allSums.push(...[i]);
```

Should be:

```
allSums.push( i );
```

Answer (score 1):

Realised this could easily be achieved by adding a spread operator before pushing to allSums.

```
for (let i = minNumber; i <= maxNumber; i++) {
    allSums.push(...[i]);
  }
```